# How to mount purestorage volume as a VMware datastore in vCenter using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vmware, vcenter, pyvmomi

I have purestorage volume and vcenter in my environment. As i want to add/provision purestorage volume as a datastore in vmware vcenter using python script using python pyvmomi package. Its not working as expected.

I tried the below using pyvmomi python package, but it is not working as expected

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
from pyVmomi import vim
import purestorage
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)

import ssl

s=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE



def add_pure_volume_as_datastore():
    # Pure Storage array details
    pure_array = '192.168.0.106'
    pure_api_token = '125cfec6-560a-ca26-e7af-27be4234d3959'
    pure_array_name = 'purefa1.lab.local'
    pure_vol_name = 'ds-vm-01'

    # VMware vCenter details
    vcenter_ip = '192.168.0.185'
    vcenter_user = 'administrator@vsphere.local'
    vcenter_password = 'admin@123'
    datacenter_name = 'dc'
    cluster_name = 'lab'
    esxi_hostname = 'esxi1.lab.local'
    port=443
    # Connect to Pure Storage array
    pure = purestorage.FlashArray(pure_array, api_token=pure_api_token)

    # Get volume information
    volume = pure.get_volume(pure_vol_name)

    # Connect to vCenter
    service_instance = SmartConnect(host=vcenter_ip, user=vcenter_user, pwd=vcenter_password, port=port,sslContext=s,disableSslCertValidation=True)
    
    print(vcenter_ip)
    # Get datacenter
    content = service_instance.RetrieveContent()
    datacenter = None
    for dc in content.rootFolder.childEntity:
        if isinstance(dc, vim.Datacenter) and dc.name == datacenter_name:
            datacenter = dc
            break

    if not datacenter:
        print(f"Datacenter '{datacenter_name}' not found.")
        return

    # Find the cluster
    cluster = None
    for c in datacenter.hostFolder.childEntity:
        if isinstance(c, vim.ClusterComputeResource) and c.name == cluster_name:
            cluster = c
            break

    if not cluster:
        print(f"Cluster '{cluster_name}' not found.")
        return

    # Find the host
    host = None
    for h in cluster.host:
        if h.name == esxi_hostname:
            host = h
            break

    if not host:
        print(f"ESXi host '{esxi_hostname}' not found in cluster '{cluster_name}'.")
        return

    # Create a spec for the new datastore
    spec = vim.host.DatastoreSystem.CreateVmfsDatastoreSpec()
    spec.vmfs = vim.host.VmfsDatastoreCreateSpec()
    spec.vmfs.volumeName = volume['name']
    spec.vmfs.extent = [vim.host.VmfsDatastoreExpandSpec(
        devicePath=f'/vmfs/devices/disks/{volume["source"]["serial"]}:1',
        partition=None
    )]

    # Create the datastore
    host.configManager.datastoreSystem.CreateVmfsDatastore(spec=spec)

    # Disconnect from Pure Storage array and vCenter
    pure.invalidate_cookie()
    connect.Disconnect(service_instance)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_pure_volume_as_datastore()
```

while i am executing the above code . i am getting the error like below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_pure_datastore.py", line 91, in <module>
    add_pure_volume_as_datastore()
  File "add_pure_datastore.py", line 75, in add_pure_volume_as_datastore
    spec = vim.host.DatastoreSystem.CreateVmfsDatastoreSpec()
  File "/home/student/venv/ansible_pure/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyVmomi/VmomiSupport.py", line 202, in __getattr__
    return super(LazyType, self).__getattribute__(attr)
AttributeError: type object 'vim.host.DatastoreSystem' has no attribute 'CreateVmfsDatastoreSpec'
```